# Why loading a 2d array with PIL.Image.fromarray mode="L" change the image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Why this code plot different images?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

x = (np.random.random((32,32))*255).astype(np.int16)

img1 = Image.fromarray(x, mode='L')
img2 = Image.fromarray(x)

plt.imshow(img1, cmap='gray')
plt.imshow(img2, cmap='gray')
```

see images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See PIL image modes [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes).

Comment: L = 8-bit pixels, black and white.. All values are 0-255.. Why are the images not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL requires `L` mode images to be 8-bit, see [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes). So, if you pass in your 16-bit image, where every high byte is zero, every second pixel will be black.

Comment: Thanks you! It is the case